# MVVM fresh vs MVVM light xamarin forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light, freshmvvm

I struggle to understand difference between mvvm fresh & mvvm light, Or I can say I am just jumping into it. So anybody just shed a light on it to be comfort to use it with xamarin.forms application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used FreshMVVM in couple of mobile apps for both Small and Tablet devices. FreshMvvm is very light yet still gives you all the features you need and it is **specifically designed to work on Xamarin Forms**. It adds extra parts to existing Xamarin Forms capabilities like :

- ViewModel Navigation
- IOC
- Automatic Wiring of ViewModels and Page events like (Appearing, Disappearing etc.)
- It gives you the functionalities like Init and ReverseInit
- It has built in Dialog service (alerts)
- It supports Simple navigation, MasterDetail navigation and Tabbed Navigation
- The Naming Conventions used are simple
- It is very light and easy to implement

They have a very nice reference and detailed information in their project site. 
https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm

**Update : What about MvvmLight?**

All of these frameworks provides common features. Because the goal of all of them is same - providing cross platform tools that would support all of the above features I listed for FreshMvvm. The only differences however may be some of them might have some more features included and the way of implementing their Base Classes.

Recommendation for you : You should learn FreshMvvm (more light and easy to learn) and MvvmCross. These 2 are the current popular ones for Xamarin and Xamarin Forms platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You haven't mention anything about light mvvm, is that not worth using for mobile app.

Comment: @Arvindraja Im sorry. I did't mention about that because I didn't used that. See the updates.